# In which city is "The Crow" set?

Tags: comics, the-crow

*The Crow*'s [IMDb trivia page](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109506/trivia?ref_=tt_trv_trv) states that the movie was set in Detroit.

I don't remember seeing that in the comic books. Is there someplace in the comics that mentions where it happens? Also, do we have conclusive proof where the *movie* is set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the movie, the city is explicitly Detroit.

> Which of you [Motor City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_City_(disambiguation)) motherfuckers wants to bet me...

As confirmed in the [film's script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Crow,-The.html):

> **EXT. DETROIT RIVER SHIPYARD** - NIGHT
>
> *The T-bird careens through dockside silence, alone, then fishtails,
>   SCREECHING, to a lung-compressing halt.*

---

The comic [*The Crow* - Book #1 (Pain)](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6049170-the-crow-volume-1) also places the events in Detroit as shown with this bin of the "Detroit News":

[image: newspaper bin reading "The Detroit News"]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it was definitely Detroit! Do you know about [Devil's Night](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil's_Night)?

Since I was born in Detroit and raised in a suburb outside the city. I have since (unfortunately) moved to the Pacific North West. No one knows about Devil's Night out here. I was surprised at this.

I remember Devil's Night, the night before Halloween, was always a big deal. Toilet papered trees, egged houses and cars, fires being set in abandoned houses throughout the city and being told to make sure animals were inside and safe scared the crap out of me as a little kid. It was a big deal.

Anyways... that's another reference to tell you it's set in Detroit. After doing some research as to why no one out west here was familiar with this night, it was because it's a Detroit thing. That's where it (Devil's Night) originated.

Another key reference that tells me that is where the Crow resided.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  "Devil's Night" is not *exclusive* to Detroit, but as noted in the accepted answer there are specific references to Detroit.  Perhaps you wanted to comment on the existing answer instead?  Please read [answer].

Comment: This has the seed of a good answer, but is currently very jumbled.